# Popup onselect event

Tags: javascript, html, laravel, vue.js

I am currently working with the Laravel Framework and I am working on a webpage that will allow a user to enter a start and end date in order to search through lists of tasks (by that filter). So far, a user can decide from a dropdown list if the date is BEFORE, is ON or is AFTER a certain date that gets selected from an html5 calendar (input type =date). What I'm trying to do is now add an additional option for them to select the start date/end date to be IN BETWEEN two dates. So I preferably want them to select the ' In between ' option, which should trigger a calendar (or two actually) when selected that will allow them to pick those two dates and allow me to store those two values.

I'm new to Javascript/HTML so any help would be very much appreciated!

Here is what I have so far in my HTML file:

```
<h6 style="float:left">Filter By Date:</h6>

            <div style="float:left;clear:left;">
                <label for="start">Start Date </label>

                <select name="start_op" v-model="filter.start_option" @change="getVueTasks(pagination.current_page)"> <!--As soon as they select a department, call getVueTasks to filter what tasks are displayed-->
                    <option value="lt">Is Before</option>
                    <option value="eq" selected>Is On</option>
                    <option value="gt">Is After</option>
                    <option value="bt">Is Between</option>
                </select>
                <br/>
                <input type="date" id="start" v-model="filter.start" @change="getVueTasks(pagination.current_page)">
            </div>
            <div style="float:left">
                <label for="end">End Date </label>

                <select name="end_op" v-model="filter.end_option" @change="getVueTasks(pagination.current_page)"> <!--As soon as they select a department, call getVueTasks to filter what tasks are displayed-->
                    <option value="lt">Is Before</option>
                    <option value="eq" selected>Is On</option>
                    <option value="gt">Is After</option>
                    <option value="bt">Is Between</option>
                </select>
                <br/>
                <input type="date" id="end" v-model="filter.end" @change="getVueTasks(pagination.current_page)">
            </div>
```

Note: I do have a separate vue/js file that handles mainly back-end stuff.

Comment: Are you stuck using the calendar option you have now? Because the bootstrap datepicker library handles all those cases for you. Its very easy to work with also. Have a look : https://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

Comment: Oh I appreciate that link thank you. I'm just having trouble figuring out how to get an onselect event (if the option 'In between' is selected) to prompt open a calendar. So using the type = date is fine for me in html; I just dont know how to get the actual option to prompt that open...

Comment: @Y.Ben Remember to polyfill if you don't use a package that already does - http://caniuse.com/#feat=input-datetime

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this -

```
      <select name="start_op" id="start_op">
         <option value="lt">Is Before</option>
         <option value="eq" selected>Is On</option>
         <option value="gt">Is After</option>
         <option value="bt">Is Between</option>
      </select>
      <br/>
      <input type="date" id="start">
```

In jquery -

```
      $(function() {
         $("#start_op").on("change",function() {
            var st_date= this.value;
            if (st_date=="") return; // please select - possibly you want something else here
            $('#start').click(); 
         }); 
      });
```

Hope this will helpful for you.